# How to Move code from jsfiddle to local system for testing

Tags: url, data-binding, knockout.js

This similar to Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693170/changed-version-of-knockout-js

I would like move the code from jsfiddle to local system for testing. The code works for adds, checked, delete. But, what it does not do is load the fake data from within the model.js. I have changed /echo/json. to local url. What else do I need to do? Using latest firefox.

model.js >>>>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var fakeData = [{
    "title": "Wire the money to Panama",
    "isDone": true},
{
    "title": "Get hair dye, beard trimmer, dark glasses and passport",
    "isDone": false},
{
    "title": "Book taxi to airport",
    "isDone": false},
{
    "title": "Arrange for someone to look after the cat",
    "isDone": false}];


function Task(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.title);
    this.isDone = ko.observable(data.isDone);
}

function TaskListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newTaskText = ko.observable();
    self.incompleteTasks = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.tasks(), function(task) { return !task.isDone() && !task._destroy });
    });

    // Operations
    self.addTask = function() {
        self.tasks.push(new Task({ title: this.newTaskText() }));
        self.newTaskText("");
    };
    self.removeTask = function(task) { self.tasks.destroy(task) };
    self.save = function() {
        $.ajax("/ds", {
            data: {
                json: ko.toJSON({
                    tasks: this.tasks
                })
            },
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                alert(ko.toJSON(result))
            }
        });
    };

     //Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
    $.ajax("/ds", {
        data: {
            json: ko.toJSON(fakeData)
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var mappedTasks = $.map(data, function(item) {
                return new Task(item);
            });

            self.tasks(mappedTasks);
        }
    });                               
}

ko.applyBindings(new TaskListViewModel());

});
```

ds.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery-1.6.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>



<p>
<div class="codeRunner">

    <h3>Tasks</h3>

    <form data-bind="submit: addTask">
        Add task: <input data-bind="value: newTaskText" placeholder="What needs to be done?" />
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: tasks, visible: tasks().length > 0">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
            <input data-bind="value: title, disable: isDone" />
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeTask">Delete</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    You have <b data-bind="text: incompleteTasks().length">&nbsp;</b> incomplete task(s)
    <span data-bind="visible: incompleteTasks().length == 0"> - it's beer time!</span>

    <button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>

</div>

</p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/model.js" ></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The ajax requests in the fiddle are just mock requests to simulate real-world scenarios, they're not really necessary.. you can use that fake data without any ajax requests. For example change these parts:

```
self.save = function() {
    alert(ko.toJSON({tasks: this.tasks}));    
};


//Load initial state from server, convert it to Task instances, then populate self.tasks
var mappedTasks = $.map(fakeData, function(item) {
    return new Task(item);
});

self.tasks(mappedTasks);
```

If you want to use ajax requests to get real data, you'll need to post the data in the format required by your own server API (i.e. not with that 'json' field in the data that is used in jsfiddle's json-echo service API)

Comment: Thanks Im tring to use ajax.... The problem is json: ko.toJSON(fakeData) is trying to parse a second time or something....

Comment: to use ajax you'd need real data from your server, not fake data in your javascript.. you seem to be completely misunderstanding the example and how to use it. the ajax in the example is using jsfiddle's echo service, which you don't have on your local machine...